# Python appends to list only one data at a time from GPIO

Tags: python, list, raspberry-pi, append

so I'm just starting out with python and was refine my readings from a load cell hooked up to a raspberry pi. Heres the code:

```
hx = HX711(5, 6)
hx.set_reading_format("LSB", "MSB")
hx.set_reference_unit(26.978)
hx.reset()
hx.tare()


while True:
    for i in range (15):
        val = int(hx.get_weight(5))
        newval = abs(round((float(val/1000)),1))        
        X = []
        X.append (newval)
        print ([X])
        hx.power_down()
        hx.power_up()
```

I imagine I would get a list of readings in that time frame, perhaps 4? But I'm always getting one. The data is definitely coming in frequently enough to make a list, but my list is always one data only.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, please help greatly appreciates.

Answer (score 0):

2 things i've noticed, which are wrong :

1. you used a for loop, without using the index in any of the instructions, this for loop is inside a while loop. It's pointless, so remove it.
2. you initialize the X list in each iteration, that's why it only have one value. you may put the X = [] above the while loop.

e.g :

```
hx = HX711(5, 6)
hx.set_reading_format("LSB", "MSB")
hx.set_reference_unit(26.978)
hx.reset()
hx.tare()


while True:
    X = []
    for i in range (15):
        val = int(hx.get_weight(5))
        newval = abs(round((float(val/1000)),1))        
        X.append (newval)
        hx.power_down()
        hx.power_up()
    print ([X])
```

will show a bunch of lists of 15 values